# Is it possible to add multiple actions to a CompletableFuture with whenComplete(...)?

Tags: java, completable-future

The class `CompletableFuture` allows to add an action which is called when the future completes after calling `complete(...)`.

Can I use `whenComplete(...)` to **add multiple BiConsumer actions** for executing when completing the future and are all of them executed when the `complete(...)` method is called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, all BiConsumer actions are added and they are executed in reverse addition order when calling complete(...).

An example to demonstrate this might look like this:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("My tests ...");
        CompletableFuture<String> futureString = new CompletableFuture<String>();
        futureString.whenComplete((s,e)->System.out.println("one " + s));
        futureString.whenComplete((s,e)->System.out.println("two " + s));
        futureString.whenComplete((s,e)->System.out.println("three " + s));
        System.out.println("do something else; "+ futureString.isDone());
        futureString.complete("step(s)");
        System.out.println("Done " + futureString.isDone());
    }
}
```

When running this program, the printed result looks this:

```
My tests ...
do something else; false 
three step(s)
two step(s)
one step(s)
Done true
```

Comment: Is the reverse order a defined behavior, or might it be just coincidence or implementation detail of the JVM? If you'd had any authoritative resources to ad, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @derM That is a good question. From my understanding I would expect the triggering of the actions to be always in reverse order. But unfortunately, I do not have any authoritive resources so I cannot 100% rule out that there may be differences depending on the implementation.